# Was bedeutet "Fügteilcharakter"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Ich suchte danach im Internet und im Wörterbuch, aber ich habe dieses Wort nicht gefunden. Es stand in einem linguistischen Kontext.

Comment: Kannst Du bitte einen Beispielsatz angeben, in dem das Wort verwendet wird?

Comment: Was hast Du versucht um den Begriff selbst zu klären? Hasst Du ihn zerlegt?

Comment: Auf welche Art die Charakteristik von jem./etw. einem Fügeteil ähnlich ist, hängt stark vom Kontext ab. Bitte den Satz angeben, in dem es vorkommt.

Answer (score 10):

Laut dem Eintrag [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/F%C3%BCgteil) ist *Fügteil* in der Linguistik ein

> traditioneller Begriff für die Wortarten **Konjunktion**, **Subjunktion** und **Präposition**.

(Hervorhebung von mir).

Wenn ein Wort also *Fügteilcharakter* hat, verhält es sich wie eine Konjunktion, Subjunktion oder eine Präposition.

<sup>Ich möchte anmerken, dass ich den Begriff *Fügteil* vorher noch nie gehört oder gelesen hatte und dass ich darauf verzichten würde, ihn zu verwenden.</sup>

Comment: Hah... ich habe spontan an einen technischen Begriff für ein Bauteil gedacht

Comment: Der Begriff Funktionswörter ist glaube ich geläufiger als Fügteil, das man wohl lange suchen muß.

Answer (score 3):

Fügteilcharakter haben die Wortarten Präpositionen sowie Subjunktionen und Konjunktionen. Sie verbinden Satzglieder oder Sätze miteinander, "fügen Teile zusammen".

Z.b. Konjunktion: Ich gehe Eis essen und ins Schwimmbad.
"und" hat Fügteilcharakter und fügt die Sätze "Ich gehe Eis essen." und "[ich gehe] ins Schwimmbad." zusammen.

Z.B. Präposition: Die Tasse steht neben dem Tisch.
Präpositionen "fügen" Satzglieder oder Attribute in einen Satz.
"neben" fügt das Satzglied "neben dem Tisch" in den Satz ein.

Comment: Klingt gut. Hast du eine Quelle dafür?

Comment: Kessel/Reimann (2008): Basiswissen deutsche Gegenwartssprache. Kap II, S. 63.

https://docplayer.org/37134602-Wort-nicht-flektierbar-flektierbar-satzgliedwert-ohne-satzwert-mit-fuegteilcharakter-ohne-fuegteilcharakter.html

Comment: @LuisaSchönwerth: Willkommen bei German SE! Die Quellenangabe würde besser in die Antwort passen (Edit-Knopf), da findet man sie leichter und Kommentare werden manchmal gelöscht oder verschoben.